# How to get table header cell's name when am using colspan peoprty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here I want to get the header cells name from table when am clicking on td who has specific class and colspan property, means when am clicking on td who has colspan property that should show all it's header cells name covered by it
like bellow snap
[image]

i have a code that is returning only the first header cell name the script code is as bellow

```
$('#example').on('click', ' td.displaydata', '.multiple', function (e) {
        var rowheader = e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex];
        alert("header=" + rowheader.innerHTML);
});
```

HTML is as bellow

```
<table border="1" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rooms</th>
            <th>08:00-09:00</th>
            <th>09:00-10:00</th>
            <th>10:00-11:00</th>
            <th>11:00-12:00</th>
            <th>12:00-13:00</th>
            <th>13:00-14:00</th>
            <th>14:00-15:00</th>
            <th>15:00-16:00</th>
            <th>16:00-17:00</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td  id="1_4" class="displaysingledata>row1</td>
            <td class="displayMultipledata" colspan="2">
                <span id="id_1_0" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td  id="1_2" class="displaysingledata"></td>
            <td  id="1_3"></td>
            <td class="displayMultipledata" colspan="2">
               <span id="id_1_4" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td  id="1_6"></td>
            <td  id="1_7" class="displaysingledata"></td>
            <td  id="1_8"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  id="2_10" class="displaysingledata">row2</td>
            <td  id="2_0"></td>
            <td  id="2_1" class="displaysingledata"></td>
            <td  id="2_2"></td>
            <td  id="2_3"></td>
            <td class="displayMultipledata" colspan="4">
                <span id="id_2_4" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td  id="2_8"></td>

        </tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

for a single cell the script i have included that is working,i need to deal with colspan which covers multiple header cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the colspan to define the number of headers you'll need.

Be aware that the index of the click cell. For example, in row1, there is a merged cell, this counts as one! Not two!

```js
$('#example').on('click', ' td.displaydata', '.multiple', function (e) {
  var colspan = $(this).attr('colspan'),
      index = $(this).index(),
      prevCells = $(this).prevAll(),
      headerTxt = '';
  $.each(prevCells, function() {
    if( $(this).attr('colspan') ) {
      index += ( $(this).attr('colspan') - 1 );
    }
  });
  for(var i=0; i<colspan; i++ ) {
    headerTxt += $('#example thead tr th:eq('+(index+i)+')').text()+"\n";
  }
  alert( headerTxt );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rooms</th>
            <th>08:00-09:00</th>
            <th>09:00-10:00</th>
            <th>10:00-11:00</th>
            <th>11:00-12:00</th>
            <th>12:00-13:00</th>
            <th>13:00-14:00</th>
            <th>14:00-15:00</th>
            <th>15:00-16:00</th>
            <th>16:00-17:00</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td  id="1_4">row1</td>
            <td class="displaydata " colspan="2">
                <span id="id_1_0" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td  id="1_2"></td>
            <td  id="1_3"></td>
            <td class="displaydata" colspan="2">
               <span id="id_1_4" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td  id="1_6"></td>
            <td  id="1_7"></td>
            <td  id="1_8"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  id="2_10">row2</td>
            <td  id="2_0"></td>
            <td  id="2_1"></td>
            <td  id="2_2"></td>
            <td  id="2_3"></td>
            <td class="displaydata" colspan="4">
                <span id="id_2_4" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td  id="2_8"></td>

        </tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## Alternativ that works on all cells

```js
$('#example').on('click', 'td:not(:first-of-type)', function (e) {
  var colspan = 1,
      index = $(this).index(),
      prevCells = $(this).prevAll(),
      headerTxt = '';
  if( $(this).attr('colspan') ) {
    colspan = $(this).attr('colspan');
  }
  $.each(prevCells, function() {
    if( $(this).attr('colspan') ) {
      index += ( $(this).attr('colspan') - 1 );
    }
  });
  for(var i=0; i<colspan; i++ ) {
    headerTxt += $('#example thead tr th:eq('+(index+i)+')').text()+"\n";
  }
  alert( headerTxt );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rooms</th>
            <th>08:00-09:00</th>
            <th>09:00-10:00</th>
            <th>10:00-11:00</th>
            <th>11:00-12:00</th>
            <th>12:00-13:00</th>
            <th>13:00-14:00</th>
            <th>14:00-15:00</th>
            <th>15:00-16:00</th>
            <th>16:00-17:00</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td  id="1_4">row1</td>
            <td class="displaydata " colspan="2">
                <span id="id_1_0" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td  id="1_2"></td>
            <td  id="1_3"></td>
            <td class="displaydata" colspan="2">
               <span id="id_1_4" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td  id="1_6"></td>
            <td  id="1_7"></td>
            <td  id="1_8"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  id="2_10">row2</td>
            <td  id="2_0"></td>
            <td  id="2_1"></td>
            <td  id="2_2"></td>
            <td  id="2_3"></td>
            <td class="displaydata" colspan="4">
                <span id="id_2_4" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td  id="2_8"></td>

        </tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: am also doing the same with single cell who has another class like
$('#example').on('click', ' td.displaydata', '.single', function (e) {
        var rowheader = e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex];
        alert("header=" + rowheader.innerHTML);
});,this code is not working when i have a colspan with some cells in same row

Comment: What you mean is that the click function should work on all cells??

Comment: i have td's in table with different different class,displaydata clas containes cells who has a colspan and i will have some td's who have another class suppose "test" so when am trying to click on test and getting it's header cell name then it is not showing exact header cell name

Comment: thanks @LinkinTED you answer s really apprciable,please check the updated HTML From QUESTION there i have added two different different classes  this one(displayMultipledata) for merged cells and this one(displaysingledata) for non-mergeed cells,by clicking on them they will show the header cells name

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).attr('colspan')` to find the colspan number for td and iterate loop through th cells to get th cell values. Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
$('#example').on('click', ' td.displaydata', '.multiple', function (e) {
  var colspan_number = parseInt($(this).attr('colspan'));
  var prevCells = $(this).prevAll();
  var previousColSpan = 0;
  $.each(prevCells, function() {
    if( $(this).attr('colspan') ) {
      previousColSpan += (parseInt($(this).attr('colspan'))-1);
    }
  });
  
  var total_cells = 1;
  if(parseInt(colspan_number)>0){
    total_cells = colspan_number;
  }
  var rowheaders = '';
  for(var i=0;i<total_cells;i++){
    rowheaders += e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[(this.cellIndex + previousColSpan + i)].innerHTML + "\n";
  }

  alert("headers : \n" + rowheaders);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="display" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rooms</th>
      <th>08:00-09:00</th>
      <th>09:00-10:00</th>
      <th>10:00-11:00</th>
      <th>11:00-12:00</th>
      <th>12:00-13:00</th>
      <th>13:00-14:00</th>
      <th>14:00-15:00</th>
      <th>15:00-16:00</th>
      <th>16:00-17:00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td  id="1_4">row1</td>
      <td class="displaydata " colspan="2">
        <span id="id_1_0" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
      </td>
      <td  id="1_2"></td>
      <td  id="1_3"></td>
      <td class="displaydata" colspan="2">
        <span id="id_1_4" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
      </td>
      <td  id="1_6"></td>
      <td  id="1_7"></td>
      <td  id="1_8"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  id="2_10">row2</td>
      <td  id="2_0"></td>
      <td  id="2_1"></td>
      <td  id="2_2"></td>
      <td  id="2_3"></td>
      <td class="displaydata" colspan="4">
        <span id="id_2_4" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
      </td>
      <td  id="2_8"></td>

    </tr>            
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Click the second merged cell in row1... ;)

Comment: yes i just checked that,and here am applying same header cell retrieving functionality for single cell as well but when am applying this code it's desturbing that code as well